# ios iphone xcode renaming a built custom framework

Tags: xcode, frameworks

Have a custom built framework using custom template, etc.  Works great.  But would like to copy the framework after the build something like.

/dir1/myframework.framework

to

/dir2/myframework-5.1.framework

When the renamed one is included in the xcode program, all is well (framework search path is correct, etc), but the link does not see the framework.  Have tried to change the renamed  info.plist items with no luck.  What could be missing...  I thought this was done before, but can't seem to get it working now.  is this a signing thing from the framework build?

Changed the following plist items

bundle name    myframework-5.1.framework
executable file (changed file name)

etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out you have to rename the object link in the framework to the same name as the framework and all is ok.

Comment: to clarify, by 'the object link' you mean the unix executable